# Command prompt uses 4x6 font for non-1 sessions, 8x12 unavailable

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, command-line, terminal-services, text-mode

I have a proble with Windows 8. If the current user session isn’t the first session started after a cold boot (basically meaning a restart in Windows 8), the console windows use very tiny 4x6 terminal font, and the 8x12 font is unavailable. I had this issue with Windows 7 before. My system language, user language and system locale are all Polish if that matters.

Comment: Maybe it will help solve the problem if I add that it appears also on some Windows 7 instances, but I've never seen it on Win7 RC or Windows 8 previews.

Comment: A similar question on SF: http://serverfault.com/q/56093/98093

Comment: Extra points for figuring out the "first session started after a cold boot" factor!

Answer (score -1):

As I've seen as an answer to another post on Microsoft website, you should change your system locale to US English (but only if you can afford wrong diacritics -- in my language they are anyway wrong, though in a more subtle way if the locale is set to my normal one)

I used 7x12 font which approximates the correct font and would only be reset if the system is buggy (like some app fiddling with the settings). This one doesn't disappear.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The issue seems to affect only systems with non-English locale and they are using non-English locale for a reason. If English locale was their preferred one, they wouldn't face the issue in the first place. Could you give us a link to that post?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/cmdexe-raster-font-8x12-is-missing/3a205183-8c99-49e4-aac3-ef020177277e

Comment: Btw it fixes the issue on my PC too. Anyway at least in my programs I find myself unable to use the extended character set for my language... Also, you can try the sfc/scannow trick, but that didn't fix it for me (I had nothing to be fixed).

Comment: The google search „missing 7x12 cmd font site:answers.microsoft.com” is a one-result search, btw :))

Comment: Yeah, it fixes missing font, but there's an obvious side effect that's mentioned in that thread: "*If your language is different from the U.S. you don't have diacritics in console aplications after change system locale.*". People don't set non-English locale for fun, they set it because they use it. Changing locale to English is not a solution.

Comment: I've seen the problem myself lol... Free Download Manager doesn't seem to be an Unicode character, so when the locale is set to my language I see the wrong diacritics (Ț as T with cedilla, anyone?). Now I see the degree character for lowercase ș (and others, just like I've seen in the first DVD players OR my smart TV having default settings lol) Yeah, that is acceptable for some, like me, not for all...

Comment: Anyway I've added a second solution, using 7x12 which is similar (not identical) to 8x12... For some reason my system has actually reset itself to THAT one lol